# Python passing arguments and class methods

Tags: python, parameter-passing, class-method

I am missing some understanding here and while I'm certain that this is in the Python documentation somewhere, I simply don't know where to look precisely.

I am trying to understand what is actually happening when I pass an argument to a function.

In other words... am I passing the object itself, am I passing a reference to the object, or am I merely passing the value.

Take the following simple example:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 0

    def inc(self):
        self.val += 1

    def set(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.val)

def sub(i,j,k):
    i.inc()
    j += 1
    k = [x+1 for x in k]
    print 'print1',i,j,k
    i.set(5)
    j = 5
    k = [5]*3
    print 'print2',i,j,k
    another(i,j,k)
    print 'print4',i,j,k

def another(l,m,n):
    l.inc()
    m += 1
    n[0] = n[0]+1
    print 'print3',l,m,n

def main():
    a = Test()
    b = 0
    c = [0]*3
    sub(a,b,c)

    print 'print5',a,b,c


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The output is pretty straight forward...

```
print1 1 1 [1, 1, 1]
print2 5 5 [5, 5, 5]
print3 6 6 [6, 5, 5]
print4 6 5 [6, 5, 5]
print5 6 0 [0, 0, 0]
```

I just want to understand what ever fine line I'm somehow crossing here.
I understand that class methods modify the object directly, but that would mean that I'm passing actual object, and not just its value/content. However, that's clearly not true for simple intergers, and even lists, but if I modify a list element, then ... magic ???

Comment: It's not the passing behaviour that's different, it's that lists are mutable and integers aren't.

Comment: but if I change the whole list ... the change is not passed...

Comment: Please read this http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables :)

Comment: That's because you don't *"change the whole list"*, you reassign the name to a completely separate object. See also http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html